# Check String whether it contains only Latin characters?

Tags: java, string, validation, gwt

Greetings,

I am developing GWT application where user can enter his details in Japanese.
But the 'userid' and 'password' should only contain English characters(Latin Alphabet).
How to validate Strings for this?

Comment: There are english characters?!?!  I thought the characters in the English language are from the Latin Alphabet.

Comment: well if he means ascii characters then I would call that english characters.. or american.

Comment: Don't allow "ABCDEF" etc. -- they're definitely French letters.

Comment: The real question is, why do you want to deliberately weaken password security?

Comment: @ArfurNarf well, this is a 13 years old question ;)

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I don't notice that it's an old question that soe random recent edit has thrown into view.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [`String#matches()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) with a bit [regex](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) for this. Latin characters are covered by `\w`.

So this should do:

```
boolean valid = input.matches("\\w+");
```

This by the way also covers numbers and the underscore `_`. Not sure if that harms. Else you can just use `[A-Za-z]+` instead.

If you want to cover [diacritical characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) as well (ä, é, ò, and so on, those are per definition also Latin characters), then you need to normalize them first and get rid of the diacritical marks before matching, simply because there's no *(documented)* regex which covers diacriticals.

```
String clean = Normalizer.normalize(input, Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
boolean valid = clean.matches("\\w+");
```

**Update**: there's an undocumented regex in Java which covers diacriticals as well, the `\p{L}`.

```
boolean valid = input.matches("\\p{L}+");
```

Above works at Java 1.6.

Comment: `\p{L}` is documented: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ubc

Comment: Drat, you're right. I would swear that I've never seen it before in the API docs for years. Are you the maintainer of the Sun API docs?

Comment: No, but I've read through that particular JavaDoc page more often than I'd like to admit ;-)

Comment: The Unicode Letter category `\p{L}` covers a LOT of non-Latin letters as well, though.

Comment: I think you want `\p{script=Latin}`

Comment: w doesn't work for apostrophes which can be common in Irish surnames (for instance)

Answer (score 12):

```
public static boolean isValidISOLatin1 (String s) {
    return StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.newEncoder().canEncode(s);
} // or "ISO-8859-1" for ISO Latin 1
```

For reference, see the [documentation on Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

Comment: I wouldn't use this as this allows the input to contain whitespace and control characters (including U+0000), which almost certainly are not welcome in a username.

Comment: Use predefined `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`

Answer (score 5):

There is my solution and it is working excellent

```
public static boolean isStringContainsLatinCharactersOnly(final String iStringToCheck)
{
    return iStringToCheck.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There might be a better approach, but you could load a collection with whatever you deem to be acceptable characters, and then check each character in the username/password field against that collection.

Pseudo:

```
foreach (character in username)
{
    if !allowedCharacters.contains(character)
    {
        throw exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For something this simple, I'd use a regular expression.

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alpha}+");

static boolean isValid(String input) {
  Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
  return m.matches();
}
```

There are other pre-defined classes like `\w` that might work better.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully used a combination of the answers of user232624, [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer) and [Tvaroh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312708/tvaroh):

```
static CharsetEncoder asciiEncoder = Charset.forName("US-ASCII"); // or "ISO-8859-1" for ISO Latin 1

boolean isValid(String input) {    
    return Character.isLetter(ch) && asciiEncoder.canEncode(username);
}
```