# Firebase Invites - SMS is not being send when using not-latin characters

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

I'm using Firebase-Invites to share an item using sms and email.

Email is working as expected but Sms is being send only if all the characters are in latin.

Note: I know there is a limit of 100 chars and i'm not exceeding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [@Oleg Cherr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35601824/1761406) answer i realise there is a limit of 40(!) instead of 100 when using not-latin characters (even only one!).

So i searched and find [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911917/1761406) answer to how to know if there is at least one not-latin character:

```
boolean valid = input.matches("\\p{L}+");
```

In this case i set another, shorter message and it seems to work perfectly.